# Effectively find smallest powers of given number

Tags: java

Given number `X`, find numbers `A` and `B` such that `X = A^B` and `A` is the smallest possible number. `B` is less than 301.

```
String[] power2(String X) {
    double n = Double.parseDouble(X);
    double i = 1;
    double j = 1;
    String[] result = {"1", "1"};
    boolean flag = false;
    if (n > 1) {
        for (i = 1; i < n; i++) {
            for (j = 1; j < 301; j++) {
                if (Math.pow(i, j) == n) {
                    flag = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (flag) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    result[0] = i + "";
    result[1] = j + "";
    return result;
}
```

This works fine but its not efficient.I am looking for more faster algorithm.

Comment: Do we know anything else about the numbers - are they integers or floating point numbers? The comparison you have won't work for doubles.

Comment: `A = Math.exp(Math.log(X) / B)`

Comment: I have edited my answer and added another solution which uses prime factors of `x` to calculate the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things:

1. Your current solution **does not** work. You don't consider case when `b = 1`, e.g. `100003 = 100003 ^ 1` but your function returns `[100003.0, 301.0]`. Due to loss of precision on doubles, your function will not return a valid result for `10000000000600000000009 = 100000000003 ^ 2`. It will keep increasing base for a very long time until it eventually returns wrong result.
2. I assume that numbers are integers. If they are not integers, than we have infinitely many combinations and we have comparison problems.
3. We will be operating on very large numbers. `2 ^ 301` is a number with 90 digits. Hence `BigInteger` is the only choice. Which unfortunately will decrease performance.
4. Your current biggest problem is that you continue inner loop (increasing exponent) even if the current result is greater than `x`. If `x = 9` then for `a = 2` and `b = 4` we already have `16` so we can stop increasing `b` and increase `a` instead (and reset `b` to 1). Your function however after checking `2 ^ 4` will check also `2 ^ 5`, `2 ^ 6` and 300 more.

Here is what I came up with:

```
private static final int MAX_B = 300;

public String[] power2(BigInteger x) {
    increaseBase:
    for (BigInteger a = BigInteger.ONE; a.compareTo(x) <= 0; a = a.add(BigInteger.ONE)) {
        for (int b = 2; b <= MAX_B; b++) {
            BigInteger result = a.pow(b);
            if (result.equals(x)) {
                return new String[] {String.valueOf(a), String.valueOf(b)};
            }
            if (result.compareTo(x) == 1) {
                continue increaseBase;
            }
        }
    }

    return new String[] {String.valueOf(x), "1"};
}
```

For values below 2 billion, it is likely to be slower, however it is able to handle numbers of any size.

Further optimizations that can be done:

- increase `a` as long as `a < roundDown(sqrt(x))` instead of until `a < x`
- revert the loops and start with large exponent, this will allow to modify the base by values different than 1 by checking how close to `x` the result was

Another idea which might be actually the most efficient one is to find prime factors of `x`. If we know that prime factors are `2, 2, 2, 2, 13, 13` then we can easily calculate that `a = 2 * 2 * 13` and `b = 2`.

**EDIT:**

Here is the implementation of my prime factors idea. Tests and imports at the bottom.

```
public class PowerCalculator {

    public String[] power2(String x) {
        @SuppressWarnings("MismatchedQueryAndUpdateOfCollection") // update via increaseCountFor method
        PrimeFactorToCount primeFactorToCount = new PrimeFactorToCount();
        BigInteger number = new BigInteger(x);
        BigInteger divisor = new BigInteger("2");

        while (!number.equals(BigInteger.ONE)) {
            if (number.remainder(divisor).equals(BigInteger.ZERO)) {
                number = number.divide(divisor);
                primeFactorToCount.increaseCountFor(divisor);
            } else {
                if (gcd(primeFactorToCount.values()) == 1) {
                    return new String[] {x, "1"};
                }
                divisor = divisor.add(BigInteger.ONE);
            }
        }

        int gcd = gcd(primeFactorToCount.values());

        return primeFactorToCount.entrySet().stream()
                .map(entry -> new Exponentiation(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()))
                .map(exponentiation -> new Exponentiation(exponentiation.base.pow(exponentiation.exponent / gcd), gcd))
                .reduce((a, b) -> new Exponentiation(a.base.multiply(b.base), gcd))
                .map(Exponentiation::asStringArray)
                .get();
    }

    private static int gcd(Collection<Integer> values) {
        return values.stream()
                .mapToLong(v -> v)
                .mapToObj(BigInteger::valueOf)
                .reduce(BigInteger::gcd)
                .map(BigInteger::intValue)
                .orElse(0);
    }

    private class Exponentiation {

        private final BigInteger base;
        private final int exponent;

        private Exponentiation(BigInteger base, int exponent) {
            this.base = base;
            this.exponent = exponent;
        }

        private String[] asStringArray() {
            return new String[] {String.valueOf(base), String.valueOf(exponent)};
        }

    }

    private class PrimeFactorToCount extends HashMap<BigInteger, Integer> {

        private void increaseCountFor(BigInteger primeFactor) {
            if (containsKey(primeFactor)) {
                put(primeFactor, get(primeFactor) + 1);
            } else {
                put(primeFactor, 1);
            }
        }

    }

}

@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class PowerCalculatorTest {

    private final uk.co.jpawlak.maptoobjectconverter.PowerCalculator powerCalculator = new uk.co.jpawlak.maptoobjectconverter.PowerCalculator();

    @Parameterized.Parameters(name = "{index}: returns {1} for {0}")
    public static Collection data() {
        return asList(new Object[][] {
                {input(3), expected(3, 1)},
                {input(7 * 7), expected(7, 2)},
                {input(2 * 2 * 2), expected(2, 3)},
                {input(3 * 3 * 5 * 5), expected(3 * 5, 2)},
                {input(3 * 3 * 5 * 5 * 5 * 5), expected(3 * 5 * 5, 2)},
                {input(3 * 3 * 3 * 3 * 3 * 3 * 5 * 5), expected(3 * 3 * 3 * 5, 2)},
                {input(2 * 3 * 3), expected(2 * 3 * 3, 1)},
        });
    }

    private final String input;
    private final String[] expected;

    public PowerCalculatorTest(String input, List<String> expected) {
        this.input = input;
        this.expected = expected.stream().toArray(String[]::new);
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        String[] actual = powerCalculator.power2(input);

        assertThat(actual, sameBeanAs(expected));
    }

    private static String input(long input) {
        return String.valueOf(input);
    }

    private static List<String> expected(long base, long exponent) {
        return ImmutableList.of(String.valueOf(base), String.valueOf(exponent));
    }

}

import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized;

import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import static com.shazam.shazamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;
import static com.shazam.shazamcrest.matcher.Matchers.sameBeanAs;
import static java.util.Arrays.asList;
```

The greatest common divisor of exponents is the final exponent of the result. If we have number `108 = 2 ^ 2 * 3 ^ 3`, the final exponent can be only `1`. That's why there is a check for this in the loop when we are about to check next divisor - so it "fails fast". It is also the reason while in the return statement, `gcd` is used as exponent. Let's have a look at number 5184:

`5184 = 2^6 * 3^4 = (2^3)^2 * (3^2)^2 = 8^2 * 9^2 = (8*9)^2 = 72^2`

Greatest common divisor of 6 and 4 is 2.

Further optimizations that can be done is in finding prime factors of the number. If you tried it on square of large prime number such as `100000020383 ^ 2` the loop will have to do over 1 billion iterations before it finds first prime factor. This however is completely different problem so I will not be describing it here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
long[] power2(long x) {
    double logX = Math.log(x);
    for (int b = 300; b > 1; --b) {
        double a = Math.exp(logX / b);
        if (Math.abs(a - Math.round(a)) < 0.0005)
            return new long[] { Math.round(a), b };
    }
    return new long[] { x, 1 };
}
```